# Automated PHP application distribution based on user signup

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

Take for instance Yahoo Mail or Twitter. When someone signs up to use their service, they'll need to automatically deploy a new database, application folder and so on - I assume!

I am planning to write an PHP application to let people add and edit invoices. Good examples would be Zoho Invoice, http://www.getballpark.com/, etc. They sure would be deploying microsites for each customer wouldn't they?

How do you do this? Would it be PHP that will handle it, or some Linux based thing.

Or if I am wrong, correct me. Maybe they have  just one huge database and manage their signups from one single application.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well most applications don't do that. Just imagine Twitter will have to deploy the whole Ruby on Rails Twitter application or the whole Yahoo Mail Server System for every single User.

You only choose the solution you suggest if users really need to customize their app (like plugging in own modules or change core functionality). Usually a (more or less) simple User, user options (like themes) and [ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) management (e.g. for the enabled modules) should be sufficient for most applications.

Comment: Well pretty much every bigger PHP Framework has such mechanisms or at least an extensive tutorial on how to implement user and rights management like the Zend ACL compontent of the Zend framework: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it is best to use one big database. Using a combination of primary keys, foregin keys, you can easily ensure that you only display data which a user's role entitles him to.

Comment: Would you be able to point me to an example of a PHP script or framework?

Comment: ...and if you want distinct domains, use wildcard domains and a wildcard vhost, then parse the relevant $_SERVER vars to find out which site the customer is on (NB this does not mean that they are authenticated/authorized)